# Something about space gates that ships can travel through

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship, teleportation

I read this book a few years back so it would be roughly 2017 or before. The main character is a young adult (possibly named Alex?) serving on the humans' space navy. The technology is such that spaceships can deploy giant gates which can teleport ships elsewhere. The gate deploy sequence takes quite a long time (because of the sheer size). The main character's best friend is a girl roughly his age with purple eyes and veins. It turns out that she's related to the race of aliens they are fighting.